# When adding new source for nuget it shows unreachable in Visual Studio for Mac 2022 Preview version

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2022, nuget-package-restore

- I have recently installed Visual Studio for Mac 2022 Preview. Now when I'm adding a source for nuget packages to restore them in my project it gives error. The source which I have added shows as `UN-REACHABLE`.
- I have attached a screenshot of the same.

I want to know what causes this problem, why its unreachable and how we can fix this? So if someone have the idea about this, please share it here. I would highly appreciate any help. Please check the screenshot.

[image]

#### Version Details

- 17.3 Preview (17.3 build 198)

```
Visual Studio Community 2022 for Mac Preview
Version 17.3 Preview (17.3 build 198)
Installation UUID: 45fdd716-7df5-4abb-8cb2-3790ad5defa5

Runtime
.NET 6.0.3 (64-bit)
Architecture: X64

Roslyn (Language Service)
4.2.0-3.22181.8+a59a22c6f3c2cc1883e20cece412209f18f4a29f

NuGet
Version: 6.0.0.262

.NET SDK (x64)
SDK: /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.300/Sdks
SDK Versions:
    6.0.300
    5.0.407
    3.1.419
    3.1.418
MSBuild SDKs: /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.300/Sdks

.NET Runtime (x64)
Runtime: /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet
Runtime Versions:
    6.0.5
    5.0.16
    3.1.25
    3.1.24

Xamarin.Profiler
Version: 1.8.0.19
Location: /Applications/Xamarin Profiler.app/Contents/MacOS/Xamarin Profiler

Updater
Version: 11

Apple Developer Tools
Xcode 13.4.1 (20504)
Build 13F100

Xamarin.Mac
Version: 8.10.0.1 (Visual Studio Community)
Hash: 568bdb24e
Branch: d17-2
Build date: 2022-04-08 18:52:56-0400

Xamarin.iOS
Version: 15.10.0.1 (Visual Studio Community)
Hash: 568bdb24e
Branch: d17-2
Build date: 2022-04-08 18:52:57-0400

Xamarin Designer
Version: 17.3.0.70
Hash: 4cf1a2208
Branch: remotes/origin/d17-3
Build date: 2022-05-25 15:23:36 UTC

Xamarin.Android
Version: 12.3.99.58 (Visual Studio Community)
Commit: xamarin-android/main/64b22fc
Android SDK: /Users/divyeshbhatt/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx
    Supported Android versions:
        12.0 (API level 31)
        11.0 (API level 30)

SDK Command-line Tools Version: 5.0
SDK Platform Tools Version: 31.0.3
SDK Build Tools Version: 30.0.3

Build Information: 
Mono: adf1bc4
Java.Interop: xamarin/java.interop/release/6.0.3xx@2a882d2d
ProGuard: Guardsquare/proguard/v7.0.1@912d149
SQLite: xamarin/sqlite/3.38.2@7b1e016
Xamarin.Android Tools: xamarin/xamarin-android-tools/main@fc3c2ac

Microsoft Build of OpenJDK
Java SDK: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/microsoft-11.jdk
11.0.12
Android Designer EPL code available here:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL

Eclipse Temurin JDK
Java SDK: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-8.jdk
1.8.0.302
Android Designer EPL code available here:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL

Android SDK Manager
Version: 17.2.0.47
Hash: d6dd135
Branch: remotes/origin/dev/tondat/main-1512059~2
Build date: 2022-05-25 15:23:29 UTC

Android Device Manager
Version: 0.0.0.1127
Hash: 4bb4d48
Branch: remotes/origin/dev/tondat/main-1536295~1
Build date: 2022-05-25 15:23:29 UTC

Build Information
Release ID: 1703000198
Git revision: b61a5879556b3b4d5270ffffd9431e5ec7db233d
Build date: 2022-05-25 15:21:16+00
Build branch: release-17.3
Build lane: release-17.3

Operating System
Mac OS X 12.3.1
Darwin 21.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 21.4.0
    Fri Mar 18 00:45:05 PDT 2022
    root:xnu-8020.101.4~15/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Comment: If you hover your mouse over the warning triangle in the "Unreachable" message, does a tooltip pop up saying additional details?

Comment: No, it shows nothing, no additional details that's why it's bit difficult to understand the reason behind this.

Comment: I assume that it either can't reach the server or can't retrieve the necessary files.

Comment: I'm able to access the nugets from path in browser so I don't think it's server issue. But thanks for comment @Jason

Comment: try to add a new other source to see if it works.

Comment: @Divyesh I have the exact same issue, were you able to fix this?

Comment: Not yet, but we can get the packages that we want in local system at one place and add reference to it.